# I make a string copy function(strcpy) but it's output is wired

Tags: c

I started learning C just a few days ago. I tried to make a copy string function like `strcpy` from `<string.h>` library. But it's output is unexpected.

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stringLen(char *l) {
    int len = 0;
    while (*l != '\0') {
        l++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main() {
    char name1[] = "Rohit";
    char name2[] = "Elijah";
    int lenOf_target = stringLen(name2);
    printf("The len of name2 is: %d\n", lenOf_target);
    copyString(name1, name2, lenOf_target);
    printf("The target name1 is 'Rohit' now %s\n", name1);
    printf("The name2(source) still is %s and the length is %d\n",
           name2, stringLen(name2));
}
```

here is the output

```
The len of name2 is: 6
The target name1 is 'Rohit' now Elijah
The name2(source) still is  and the length is 0
```

Comment: `name1` is just big enough to hold a string of length 5.  Attempting to write beyond the bounds of that array will be undefined behavior.  Try changing the first line of `main` to `char name1[256] = "Rohit";`

Comment: The function you ask about (`copyString()`) isn't included above.

Answer (score 1):

The length of array `name1` (6 bytes) is too small to receive the string `"Elijah"` (7 bytes, including the null terminator). Your program has undefined behavior.

A likely but not guaranteed explanation is `name1` and `name2` are contiguous in the program stack area and copying 7 bytes to `name1` caused the first byte of `name2` to be overwritten with a `'\0'`, the null terminator at the end of the string, causing the observed output on the third line.

You can fix the program by defining `name1` as

```
char name1[7] = "Rohit";  // or any length larger than 7
```